# R: select rows in a matrix based on rows in another matrix

Tags: r

I have two large matrices, each with a different set of data (binary and continuos), but for the same samples.

```
> head (bi.data)
  R10 R11 R2 R3 R4 R5 R7 R8 R9
1   1   0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
2   0   0  1  0  0  0  0  0  0
3   0   0  0  0  0  0  0  0  1
4   0   1  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
5   0   0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
6   0   0  0  1  0  0  0  0  0

> head(cont.data)
    Dep_Mark  Dep_Work   Dep_Ext 
1 0.00000000 1.0000000 0.0000000       
2 0.00000000 1.0000000 0.0000000
3 0.00000000 1.0000000 0.0000000      
4 0.02118644 0.7415254 0.2372881       
5 0.08833922 0.9116608 0.0000000     
6 0.08833922 0.9116608 0.0000000
```

I have to remove certain rows (samples) from the binary matrix, and I understand that there are several ways to do this, including:

```
> bi.data2 = bi.data [-c(1,10, 15, 29, 55, 87, 95, 121, 127),]
```

I would like remove the exact same rows (samples) from the continuos matrix. I know that I can do this using the same function. BUT I would like to know if there an easier way to remove rows in from matrix using a conditional argument.

SOMETHING LIKE THIS: cont.data2 = subset (cont.data, Where rownames (cont.data) == rownames (bi.data2))

I have to do this for several matrix sets, and the rows to be removed will be different for each set.

THANKS!

Comment: Are you sure they're matrices and not data frames?  That output looks like data frames.  Also please post the desired result based on your example data.

Comment: Maybe 
`subset(cont.data,  rownames(cont.data) %in% rownames(bi.data2))`
Or
`cont.data[row.names(cont.data) %in% row.names(bi.data2), ]` ?